# Javascript stops working when there is a second div with that class on the page

Tags: javascript

I have some code I am using to autoplay a Summary Block in Squarespace. It is a workaround done by automatically clicking the next button every three seconds. The code also has a shut off in case a viewer clicks the previous button.

This is working great except if there is more than one Summary Block on the page. As soon as there is more than one, the code doesn't run. I thought I was getting around more than one by having it loop through all of the Summary Blocks but it doesn't seem to be working (maybe I am misunderstanding the loop?).

```
  var summaryCarousel = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-block-summary-v2");
  for (var i = 0; i < summaryCarousel.length; i++) {
    var carouselNextArrow = summaryCarousel[i].querySelector(".summary-carousel-pager-next");
    var carouselPrevArrow = summaryCarousel[i].querySelector(".summary-carousel-pager-prev");
    carouselPrevArrow.addEventListener("click", carouselStopAutoplay, false);
  }

  function carouselClickNext() {
    carouselNextArrow.click();
  }

  function carouselStopAutoplay() {
    clearInterval(carouselAutoplay);
  }

  let carouselAutoplay = setInterval(carouselClickNext, 3000);
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thank you to charlietfl below for helping me out. The code is now working except it is making the Squarespace Editor open after every click. I came up with this work around to have it only apply the code on the live version of the site. However, if anyone has any ideas as to why the code is doing this, it would be greatly appreciated!!

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("squarespace") < 0 ) {  
    var summaryCarousel = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-block-summary-v2");
    for (var i = 0; i < summaryCarousel.length; i++) {
      initAutoClick(summaryCarousel[i]);
    }

    function initAutoClick(parent){

      var carouselNextArrow = parent.querySelector(".summary-carousel-pager-next");
      var carouselPrevArrow = parent.querySelector(".summary-carousel-pager-prev"); 

      carouselPrevArrow.addEventListener("click", carouselStopAutoplay, false);


      function carouselClickNext() {
        carouselNextArrow.click();
      }

      function carouselStopAutoplay() {
        clearInterval(carouselAutoplay);
      }

      let carouselAutoplay = setInterval(carouselClickNext, 3000);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is after the loop completes the value of `carouselNextArrow` will be the one in the last summary block only. Also the setInterval would not be instance specific either

You could wrap this in a function to call for each summary block instance.

```
var summaryCarousel = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-block-summary-v2");
for (var i = 0; i < summaryCarousel.length; i++) {
  // call function for each instance
  initAutoClick(summaryCarousel[i])
}

function initAutoClick(parent){

  var carouselNextArrow = parent.querySelector(".summary-carousel-pager-next");
  var carouselPrevArrow = parent.querySelector(".summary-carousel-pager-prev"); 

  carouselPrevArrow.addEventListener("click", carouselStopAutoplay, false);


  function carouselClickNext() {
    carouselNextArrow.click();
  }

  function carouselStopAutoplay() {
    clearInterval(carouselAutoplay);
  }

  let carouselAutoplay = setInterval(carouselClickNext, 3000);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that code is not working. I checked it on just one Summary Block and it didn't work on there either.

Comment: Any errors thrown in browser dev tools console?

Comment: It looks like there is an incorrect bracket after initAutoClick(parent). I changed it and the code works... except it is making the Squarespace Editor go crazy. There are no errors thrown in dev tools but there is some warnings saying that there is "Cross-Origin Read Blocking". Specifically it mentions carouselClickNext, setInterval, and initAutoClick.

Comment: Ahh yes. Definitely a typo on my part. I have no familiarity with squrespace to know why editor going crazy

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I did come up with a little workaround. I'll update my code above...